# PageFunction is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation project

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I'm aware this is the same issue as raised in ["PageFunction is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project" 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547990/pagefunction-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-projec) - however, I'm unsure as to how to apply the workaround mentioned there, and thought it may be more appropriate to raise this as a separate question. Apologies in advance if this is against the site ethos.

To summarise the problem: I have a C# Visual Studio 2010 WPF project that's a couple of years old, which I'm now trying to open in Visual Studio 2012. Although the project still builds and runs fine, I need to edit the XAML markup, and the Design view in VS2012 complains of "Invalid Markup". The exact error it's tripping up on is:

> Page Function is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation
>   (WPF) project

The start of the XAML looks like:

```
 <PageFunction
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" 
    x:Class="MyProject.WizardPage1"
    x:TypeArguments="local:WizardResult"
    KeepAlive="True"
    WindowTitle="My Project" Height="350" ShowsNavigationUI="False" Width="700" >
```

As mentioned in the original question, there are reports of this exact issue on [this](http://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723887/pagefunction-not-supported-and-typearguments-not-defined-in-xaml-namespace%20%27%27this%27%27) Microsoft page. There is a workaround mentioned involving "ViewBase", but I cannot see how this relates to the PageFunction problem (I'm very new to XAML so I may be missing something simple).

I've tried opening the project in Blend for VS2012 (the new Preview version that supports non-Windows 8 projects), but that gives the same error about PageFunction not being supported. The recent Update 1 for VS2012 hasn't fixed the problem either.

Can anyone advise what I need to change in my XAML or code-behind in order to be able to visually edit this page?

Or should I give up and just re-download VS2010 in order to edit this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the workaround, you'll need to create a class which derives from `PageFunction<WizardResult>`, and then update your XAML to inherit from that class.

**Class:**

```
public class WizardResultPageFunction : PageFunction<WizardResult>
{
}
```

**Code-behind:**
Either change the class to inherit from your new class, or remove the base-class declaration completely and let the XAML define the base class:

```
public partial class WizardPage1
// or: 
// public partial class WizardPage1 : WizardResultPageFunction 
{
   ...
}
```

**XAML:**
Replace the `PageFunction` with `local:WizardResultPageFunction` and remove the `x:TypeArguments` attribute:

```
<local:WizardResultPageFunction 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" 
   x:Class="MyProject.WizardPage1"
   KeepAlive="True"
   WindowTitle="My Project" Height="350" ShowsNavigationUI="False" Width="700"
>
```